# how do I pass on a javascript function with a jquery submission to another php file?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a jquery shopping cart, but when data is sent to my php file, I can't close my shopping cart. How do I send the function to my php file?

Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var shopcart = document.getElementById('shopcart-grid');
        [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.checkout' )  )   
.forEach( function( el ) {
 var openCtrl = el.querySelector( '.checkout__button' ),
                    closeCtrl = el.querySelector( '.checkout__cancel'   
);

                openCtrl.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    classie.add( el, 'checkout--active' );
                    classie.add( shopcart, 'shopcart-grid--highlight' 
);
                } );

                closeCtrl.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                    classie.remove( el, 'checkout--active' );
                    classie.remove( shopcart, 'shopcart-grid--
highlight' );
                } );
            } );
        })();
</script>
```

Comment: how do you send the data? i can neither find an ajax request here, nor there is a form submit

Comment: 'sending a function to PHP' sounds meaningless. Javascript and PHP cannot share functions. Real functions, that is. Emptying a shopping cart after completion of an order is always somewhat difficult, mainly because it is not always clear when the order is finished. Is it when the online payment is completed? When the confirmation page is reached? You've got a make a clear choice and put the code to clear the basket there.

Comment: If you want to share data from JS to PHP you should do some Ajax call. The idea is : you do something in JS, you send data from your JS to a PHP, in your PHP you do what you need with the sending data then you send back a response from your PHP to your Ajax call and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: no it is just when user deletes an item, then you can't close the shopping cart

Comment: I have a function which closes the cart when its opened but once data has been sent, it doesn't close